# animate doesn't work in if/else statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code here. It's supposed to trigger my floating menu to pop down when I scroll down the page. For testing purposes, I have the menu displayed with a margin-top of -15px when the page first loads. As expected, I can see the menu, but as soon as I scroll, the menu disappears. And that parts fine too. What's funky is that when I scroll to more than 770, it doesn't come back. I put other snippets of code in the if/else statements to confirm that the arguments were returning false/true corrrectly (they were), so I'm not sure, why the first if/else statement isn't working.

```
function showMenu() {

    if(document.body.scrollTop >= 770) {
        $("#floating-menu").animate({marginTop: "40px"}, 500);
    } else if (document.body.scrollTop < 770) {
        $("#floating-menu").animate({marginTop: "-100px"}, 500);
    }
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
   showMenu(); 

});
```

and here is my css:

```
#floating-menu {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. :-/ Apparently, I needed to use .stop().